# mysql-connector jar error on CloudBees

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish, cloudbees

I just deployed my `Java EE 7/Glassfish 4` persistence application with `CloudBees SDK`. And I add a mysql-connector jar `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` in the `META-INF/lib` folder of my webapp. I got the error as following:

```
Deploying application javaeeapp/order (environment: ): order-7.0.1.war
........................uploaded 25%
........................uploaded 50%
........................uploaded 75%
........................upload completed
deploying application to server(s)...

ERROR: Server.InternalError - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform error - plugin_setup_error: glassfish4 11 Creating application skeleton at /var/genapp/apps/1cd83989
Installing glassfish
Copying application war to /var/genapp/apps/1cd83989/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy
found 2 files matching meta-inf/lib/
Archive:  /mnt/genapp-tmp/stax-genapp-1382111428.34851/app/app.war
caution: filename not matched:  META-INF/lib/*
```

Comment: meta-inf or META-INF ? platform is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

The CloudBees platform is UNIX based (Linux) and hence case-sensitive.

Your `meta-inf` folder should be renamed to `META-INF`